# Как переместиться в начало файла, если EOF достигнут, а seekg не помогает

Tags: c++, fstream

Я читаю из файла данные

```
while (transactionData >> clientTrans)
```

Первый проход все нормально, а на втором вижу, что `transactionData.tellg() == -1`,  `transactionData.seekg(0)` не помогает.

В чем проблема подскажите, пожалуйста!?

Попробовал делать не через переопределенную операцию для `clientTrans`, а просто

```
while (transactionData >> int >> string >> string >> double)
```

текст файла

```
1 Pupkin kirill 1000
104 Krivay Katya 222
2 Derevo Lisa  100
```

Comment: `transactionData.clear(ios_base::goodbit)`?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А куда устанавливается fail bit в моем случае?

Comment: В каком смысле куда? PS: Запостил ответ.

Comment: Видимо, в transactionData, т.е. не в файл? Таким способом читать из файла данные - это нормально, или есть способ лучше?

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: Уже разобрался, что состояние потока не записывается в файл. Видимо, это элемент данных объекта класса ifstream.

Comment: Да, естественно, в файл оно не записывается.

Comment: Если вопросы кончились и всё работает, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transactionData.clear(ios_base::goodbit);
```